# How to calculate transformed data coordinates with probabilistic PCA?

Tags: pca, svd

[PPCA models](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/bishop-ppca-jrss.pdf) data with

$$X = W Y + \mu + \epsilon$$

where $X$ is data matrix of $n \times p$ size, $Y$ is "hidden" or transformed data coordinates while $W$ and $\mu$ are parameters of the model. As far as I understand, $\epsilon$ is normally distributed noise.

So, to transform $X$ to $Y$ I do

$$X - \mu - \epsilon = WY$$

$$W^{-1} (X - \mu - \epsilon) = Y$$

which for centered data and ignoring noise gives

$$W^{-1} X = Y$$

On the other hand, in conventional PCA we have

$X = USV^T$

where $V$ is matrix from principal directions, hence

$Y = XV$

this implies, that

$W^{-1}X = XV$

Is this correct relation? Can I really compute transformation into hidden space by both products?

Comment: This is all wrong. In PPCA, latent Y is distributed as standard normal. If you compute XV, you will get PC scores but they will not be standardized. Regarding PPCA, you cannot "ignore the noise". You can look up the formula for maximum likelihood Y given X in Tipping & Bishop.

Comment: I don't want to ignore the noise, I wan't to calculate $Y$ from $X$. Suppose I have $W$, $\mu$ and $\sigma$. How would I calculate reverse?

Comment: Tipping & Bishop, Eq. 9.

Comment: It is the the formula for the mean

Comment: I need to transform dataset

Comment: So what? I don't get it. You apply Eq. 9.

Comment: Shape of $X$ dataset is $N \times d$ (in B-T notation), shape of reduced dimensionality dataset $Y$ is $N \times q$, shape of formula `(9)` is $1 \times d$ so it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the "shape of formula", but Eq. 9 shows you how to transform a vector with $d$ dimensions into a vector with $q$ dimensions. If you have $N$ such vectors, then do it $N$ times, or apply a matrix multiplication to do it all at once.

Comment: Okay you are right, although I don't understand what angle brackets do there then...

Comment: Well, PPCA is *probabilistic*, that's the whole point. Given X, you have a whole distribution of $Y$, not one value. If you want one value, it makes sense to take the mean of that distribution. Brackets denote the mean. See eq. (6).

Comment: Anyway $M^{-1}W_{ML}^T$ forms some transformation matrix. What is it's difference from standard `PCA` then? It doesn't project onto principal subspace? Or it does this projection but also adds some normalization?

Comment: Did you actually read the paper? They discuss it there, right after Eq. 9 and probably in some other places too. I know that this topic can be difficult at first, but a discussion in the comments here really CANNOT replace reading the paper in terms of how much understanding you will get. I have to go now.